# Get selected option from select list

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have the following select list and jQuery code to dynamically get the selected option:

```
<select id="form_instructions_instruction_select" name="form[instructions][instruction_select]">
    <option value="-- select --"></option>
    <option value="new">new</option>
    <option value="35">first intruction test</option>
    <option value="47">testing</option>
    <option value="45">testing ... testing</option>
    <option value="48">test</option>
    <option value="49">testing new instruction</option>
</select>

$(document).ready( () => {
    $('select#form_instructions_instruction_select').on('change', () => {
        console.log( $(this).text() );
        console.log( $(this).value() );
    });
});
```

But the *text* console output returns an empty string and the *value* output returns the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function
```

I found some answers suggesting to query the select list for the option with the `option:selected` attribute. But there is no option with such an attribute whenever I select a different option.

The irony is that my code worked correctly and as expected previously. What has caused this malfunction?

Comment: `.val()` ..  not "value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully conceed that `$(this).find("option:selected").val()` ought to work but I don't know why it didn't for me.

Eventually, I thought about attempting a plain *JS* approach and came up with the following:

```
document.getElementById('form_instructions_instruction_select').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
})
```

That worked.

Answer (score 0):

To get selected text on the change dropdown, you can use this jquery syntex

```
$(this).find("option:selected").text()
```

and to get a select value on the dropdown change you can use

```
$(this).val()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('select#form_instructions_instruction_select').on("change",function(){
  alert("Text:-" + $(this).find("option:selected").text() + " and value:-"+ $(this).val())
    })
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="form_instructions_instruction_select" name="form[instructions][instruction_select]">
    <option value="-- select --"></option>
    <option value="new">new</option>
    <option value="35">first intruction test</option>
    <option value="47">testing</option>
    <option value="45">testing ... testing</option>
    <option value="48">test</option>
    <option value="49">testing new instruction</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Neeraj for you time and input. Your code makes sense and I tried exactly the same (or similar) but as I said in my description, my drop down list does not have a option:selected attribute whenever I change options. The list is generated from my Symfony application but I don't understand why. Without that attribute the code does not work in my project.